# console2 uses the wrong JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, console2

I discover something weird with console2 and thought somebody have a solution.

I have defined `JAVA_HOME` and added the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to my `Path`.
The Version of my defined `JAVA_HOME` is `jdk1.6.0`.

My System has a `jre1.5.0` installed.

If i start console2 and enter `java -version` i get the `jre1.5.0`, but why?

**EDIT:**
For everbody who runs in the same problem.
If you type "where java" you get the path to the java.exe.
My result is:
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
D:\jdk1.6.0_18\bin\java.exe

I don't know why but cmd.exe use the java.exe define in Path and console2 use java.exe in System32.

**Solution:** Delete C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

Answer (score 4):

Probably is too late, but the right answer is to update your PATH variable so that **%JAVA_VERSION%/bin** is before the **%SystemRoot%\system32;** (and similar entries).

There is no need to delete or change anything else.

Hope it helps!
Iván.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, your `java` path from `java -version` is taken from registries, Java installer does this in windows registries

Comment: Yeah but if i use instead of console2 cmd i get the right java version!

Comment: Check in the setting the which shell did you gave to Console2, with use of CTRL+S (in console2) > and then Console (right)> Shell

Comment: I tried it with cmd.exe and with the Powershell. Both had the same behavior.

Comment: didnt get you here, can you elaborate? you tried with "cmd.exe" as Shell to console2 or ran it in "cmd.exe"

Comment: I used the command "java -version" in cmd.exe, powershell, console2. Result is that cmd.exe and the powershell have the right java version, but console2 do not. In Console2 you can set a path to the shell that console2 should use. Here i also test it with a path to cmd.exe and powershell. With the same result. The java version is wrong in console2.

Comment: thats wierd! shouldn't be happened as console2 uses the underlying shell to do all the stuff